# Javascript - iframe is not loading because variable is not defined

Tags: jquery, iframe

i want some assistance with my script .Im newbie in programming and jquery  so the following code is not optimized and im sure the experienced programmers will be shocked with my style .

Im adding within an empty div content which i read it from another page using Jquery Load method.This works fine but now im trying to extend it without success.

i cannot make an iframe to load a source .The url source contain two variables.It seems that the one (id1) is not defined while im adding the source.I checked it also in console log and it is not defined .The iframe returns error:SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/sslnavcancel.htm . When im running the url without var id1 it works fine
It is not clear to me,how works  the the scope of the variables and the best practice.In order to make something work, i make mess without thinking in a more efficient and long run way .Could you please help me ? 
the code is the following:

```js
 

$(document).ready(function(){

 var div1 =$("<div></div>")
 
     var div5=$("<div></div>")
 var iframe1=$("<iframe></iframe>")
 
 
 
//assign id's to divs
 div1.attr("id", "div1");
 
    div5.attr("id", "div5");
    iframe1.attr("id", "myframe");
 
   $("#container1").find(".SectionData").append(div5);
   $("#container1").find(".SectionData").append(iframe1);

 
 var posts= $('a.featuredblog_entry_title').map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('href'); 
 });
  
 //if id exists then extract the id of the entry
     if(posts[0]){
 id1 = posts[0].substring(posts[0].lastIndexOf('_') + 1); id1 of the the entry
 }

//id of blog should change according to the blog id of the page
 
 $("#container").find(".SectionData").append(div1);
 
//array of links to view entry page of each post
 var posts2 = ["//address/address/"+id1];
 
if(id1!=''){ //use ajax to load content from view entry page
    $('#div1').load(posts2[0] + " .shadow3", function() {
   //add title and make it link
  $('#div1').find('.entry_OTName').replaceWith(function() {
   var title = $(this).text();
   $(this).attr("class","headtitle");
   return '<a href="' + posts2[0] + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a>';
  });
  
  Replace1();
 });
  

  
  function Replace1(){
   var minimized_elements = $('#div1').find('.richtext');
   var minimize_character_count = 100;    
   
   minimized_elements.each(function(){    
         
    var t = $(this).text();        
    if(t.length < minimize_character_count ) return;
   
    var h = $(this).html();
    
    var counter;
    $(this).html('<span class="more2">'+ t.slice(0,minimize_character_count)+'...<a href="#" class="more" id="more1"> View More 

</a></span>'+
    '<span style="display:none;">'+ h +' <br/><a href="#" class="less">View Less</a></span><br/><span>The Article Viewed by '+counter+' 

users</span>');
  
    $('#more1').click(function() { 
   
     $('#div5').load('/address/addresss/...', function() {
                    if($('#ReportTable tr:eq(1)')!=0){
       var myurl = "/address/addresss/..."+id1+"&link="+var2;
       $('#myframe').attr('src',myurl);
       counter = $('#ReportTable tr:eq(2)').val();
 console.log("the if is true so the counter is:"+counter);

       }
      else {
      counter = $('#ReportTable tr:eq(2)').val();
console.log("Else executed, counter is "+counter);

          }
     });
    }); 
  
   });
   
            
  }
```

Comment: You're defining the variable `id1` within an `if` statement, so if that statement is false, then the variable will never be defined.

Comment: Thanks, well the if statement is, for sure, true, i checked it within console and after the if i can see the value of id1

Comment: Another issue is that you're not declaring it as a variable, it should be `var id1 =` instead of just `id1 =` Alternatively, you could declare it as an empty variable at the top(where you're defining your other variables) like this: `var id1;` and then you shouldn't have to modify the code within the `if` statement.

Comment: When you say top ,do you mean just after $(document).ready(function(){ ?

Comment: Yep, right near your other variable declarations. Doesn't really matter where you put it as long as it's before the spot where you're trying to access the variable, but pest practice is to declare all your global variables at the top.

Comment: well i did it but again the variable is not defined ...

Comment: Post your updated code. Would also help if you posted the HTML associated with this code as well as any errors you're getting in the developer console.